# Adding new sudo user using ansible - "password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD" message

Tags: vagrant, ansible

I'm using Vagrant (Virtual Box provider) to setup a local Virtual Machine. I'm also using ansible and more specific ansible_local (Vagrant plugin) to deploy some tools into the VM.

Initially I'm trying to create a new user following the ansible documentation.

```
---
- name: Master Node
hosts: 127.0.0.1
connection: local
user: root
vars_files:
    - vars/vars.yml
vars:
    username: nikolas

tasks:
- name: Adding user
  user: name={{username}} shell=/bin/bash groups=root append=yes password={{pass}}
  sudo: yes

- name: Placing RSA key
  authorized_key: user={{username}} key="{{ lookup('file', 'id_rsa.pub') }}"
  sudo: yes
```

When I run the playbook, I get this message:

> PLAY [Master Node] ************************************************************
>
> GATHERING FACTS ***************************************************************
>   ok: [127.0.0.1]
>
> TASK: [Adding user] **************************************************
>   changed: [127.0.0.1] => {"changed": true, "comment": "", "createhome": >true, "group": 1001, "groups": "root", "home": "/home/nikolas", "name": >"nikolas", "password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD", "shell": "/bin/bash", >"state": "present", "system": false, "uid": 1001}
>
> TASK: [Placing RSA key] *******************************************************
>   changed: [127.0.0.1] => {"changed": true, "key": "ssh-rsa >AAAAB3N....public_rsa_key", "key_options": null, >"keyfile": "/home/desmotes/.ssh/authorized_keys", "manage_dir": true, >"path": null, "state": "present", "unique": false, "user": "nikolas"}
>
> PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************
>   127.0.0.1                  : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    >failed=0

"password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD"
As a result,  when i am trying to logged in as nikolas in the VM to get authentication error.

Do you know where is my mistake ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to modified your `user` creation task like this:

```
- name: Adding user
  user: name={{username}} shell=/bin/bash groups=root append=yes password={{ pass | password_hash('sha512') }}
  sudo: yes
```

Hope that help you.

Comment: I tried your code but i received failed message. 
For example failed: [127.0.0.1] => {"failed": true}
msg: this module requires key=value arguments
FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting

Comment: on which step you got? can you please paste the full track.

Comment: I changed tactic and i used the password_hash('sha512').
For example i added this var :
> password: "{{'password'|password_hash('sha512')}}"

and change a bit the user task like: 
> user: name={{username}} password={{ password }}

Finally nothing changed:

ok: [127.0.0.1] => {"append": false, "changed": false, "comment": "", "group": 1001, "home": "/home/nikolas", "move_home": false, "name": "nikolas", "password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD", "shell": "/bin/sh", "state": "present", "uid": 1001}

Comment: thnx for the help. I used your proposal and added vault mechanism and finally my ansible-playbook is ok. In the following link, you will find my correct [commit](https://github.com/Desmotes/ProvisioningMasterNode/commit/a0da1f586e94cc620474451476bba64d00509236).