# Creating an Ubuntu user with Ansible on a Vagrant box fails to create a password

Tags: vagrant, ansible, ubuntu-16.04, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create an new user `deployer` on a vagrant virtual machine that runs ubuntu-16.04 Xenial. The user creation seems to work( the user names are added to `/etc/passwd`)

```
$ cat /etc/passwd | grep deployer
deployer1:x:1001:1001::/home/deployer1:/bin/bash
deployer2:x:1002:1003::/home/deployer2:
deployer1000:x:1003:1004::/home/deployer1000:/bin/bash
deployershell:x:1004:1005::/home/deployershell:/bin/bash
```

However I'm unable to login neither directly via `ssh`:

```
$ ssh deployer@local-box-2
deployer@local-box-2's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
deployer@local-box-2's password: 
Permission denied, please try again.
```

nor via `su deployer` after ssh-ing with an existing user `vagrant`:

```
vagrant@local-box-2:~$ su deployer
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
```

I've tried to create the user by using both the ad-hoc ansible commands:

```
$ ansible all -m user -a 'name=deployer group=admin update_password=always password=rawpass2 state=present shell=/bin/bash force=yes' -u vagrant -b -vvvv


local-box-2 | SUCCESS => {
    "append": false, 
    "changed": true, 
    "comment": "", 
    "group": 1001, 
    "home": "/home/deployer", 
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "append": false, 
            "comment": null, 
            "createhome": true, 
            "expires": null, 
            "force": true, 
            "generate_ssh_key": null, 
            "group": "admin", 
            "groups": null, 
            "home": null, 
            "login_class": null, 
            "move_home": false, 
            "name": "deployer1", 
            "non_unique": false, 
            "password": "VALUE_SPECIFIED_IN_NO_LOG_PARAMETER", 
            "remove": false, 
            "seuser": null, 
            "shell": "/bin/bash", 
            "skeleton": null, 
            "ssh_key_bits": 0, 
            "ssh_key_comment": "ansible-generated on local-box-2", 
            "ssh_key_file": null, 
            "ssh_key_passphrase": null, 
            "ssh_key_type": "rsa", 
            "state": "present", 
            "system": false, 
            "uid": null, 
            "update_password": "always"
        }, 
        "module_name": "user"
    }, 
    "move_home": false, 
    "name": "deployer", 
    "password": "NOT_LOGGING_PASSWORD", 
    "shell": "/bin/bash", 
    "state": "present", 
    "uid": 1001
}
```

and by running a playbook

```
$ ansible-playbook local-box.yml

- name:  Add 'deployer' user
    hosts: local-box-2
    gather_facts: false
    remote_user: vagrant
    become: true
    become_method: sudo
    become_user: root
    tasks:
    - remote_user: vagrant
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: root
      group:
        name: admin
        state: present
    - remote_user: vagrant
      become: true
      become_method: sudo
      become_user: root
      user:
        name: deployer
        groups: admin
        append: yes
        shell: /bin/bash
        password: rawpass2
        state: present
```

Again, both create the users, but apparently none of them set the password.

What do you the cause might be?

**Later Edit:**

Apparently, if I pass the raw password to a hash filter then I will be able to login using the (unhashed) raw password. I would love an explaination on why that is the case.

```
password: "{{ 'rawpass2' | password_hash('sha512') }}"
```

***Note:***
*This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38561943/5920988) gave me the idea to try using filters .*

Comment: So what is the question here? Ansible documentation is clear about the requirement. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/user_module.html and gives https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding new sudo user using ansible - "password": "NOT\_LOGGING\_PASSWORD" message](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38557537/adding-new-sudo-user-using-ansible-password-not-logging-password-message)

Answer (score 0):

Ansible is not failing to set the password; the issue is in how passwords work on linux.

A linux user password is stored in a hashed form, the cleartext is not stored anywhere on the system. When you login the password you enter is hashed and compared with the stored value.

When you specify a password during the user creation process in ansible, it must be the **already hashed form** as noted in the doc links in your question.

If you look at /etc/shadow on the system where you created the user you will see something like this (the second field is the password value):

`deployer:rawpass2:17165:0:99999:7:::`

which shows you that the string you supplied was used directly as the hashed password value. Of course when you try to login and specify `rawpass2`, the login code hashes that and compares it to the stored value and they don't match. This is why you have to pass the already hashed value to ansible.

Answer (score 0):

ansible user password should be hashed. https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples/blob/master/language_features/user_commands.yml

Please follow the document "http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/faq.html#how-do-i-generate-crypted-passwords-for-the-user-module" for has password generation in ansible

```
  - remote_user: vagrant
  become: true
  become_method: sudo
  become_user: root
  user:
    name: deployer
    groups: admin
    append: yes
    shell: /bin/bash
    password: hass_value_of_rawpass2
    state: present
```

To create hash password of rawpass2 as Example:

```
     cmadmin@ansible:~$ mkpasswd --method=sha-512
     Password:    <rawpass2>
 $6dsdwqrc3124JsO9gVJZUWa$sgKxTKz4RbZnIZIvhotWHAHQL1o3/V5LTrrEJCe9DDkTW3Daut.nIpU9Qa0kDWdMZSaxvV1
```